# Windows Explorer created divisions and removed Quick Access

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

A couple days ago, I found myself trying to clean my keyboard after forgetting to disable the keyboard, and I found my explorer to look like the following:

[image]

While this does have most of the things I saw before, Quick Access is completely gone, and there's this odd separation of folders between Home, my main folders, and drives. What did I do here and how could I revert it back to the default view?

Comment: So far as I can see, Quick Access was removed in 22H2 with the addition of Home (and you can add there) and Tabbed Explorer.  This is the new Windows 11 File Explorer.

Comment: ah yes, I see, that makes more sense. I think I'd been unknowingly using Home rather than Quick Access. however, I feel like this separator bar along with the different areas weren't here before; is there a way to just remove the middle areas? they're clearly redundant if I'm relying on Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 22H2 File Explorer is very new.

**(1)** File Explorer now uses Tabs so you can get multiple view in one File Explorer Window.

You can still set Folder Options to have a new File Explorer Window open on a different folder.

I like the One Window View.

**(2)** Then the new Home icon takes the place of Quick Access and you can add favorites here.

[image: Windows 22H2 file explorer]

Comment: this makes a lot of sense... was fiddling around with it and opening one folder seemed to just explode the left view, so I disabled the "expand current folder". this seems to be more or less what I had before, so this makes a lot more sense! thanks :D